# Refer to my sqlConnection in mySqlCommand

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

My connection button works..

> ```
> private void connectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             username = initialTf.Text;
>             adress = adressTf.Text;
>
>             connect conn = new connect();
>             conn.myConnection(username, adress);
>         }
> ```

Refering to this method

> ```
> public SqlConnection myConnection(string dbName, string addr)
>         {
>             connector = new SqlConnection(
>             "Data Source=" + addr + ";" + "Initial Catalog=" + dbName +   ";Trusted_Connection=yes;");
>             try
>             {
>                 connector.Open();
>                 MessageBox.Show("Du är ansluten");
>             }
>             catch (Exception e)
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("Fail" + e);
>             }
>             return connector;
> ```

And then I added another button reading from a textField that will execute a SQL command. Problem is I don't know how to get and use the connection method.

The button code

> ```
> private void askBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>             sqlQuestion = sqlQuestiontF.Text;
>             connect conn = new connect();
>             conn.askSQL(sqlQuestion);
>
>         }
> ```

And finally the code in the connect class

```
> class connect
>     {
>         SqlConnection connector;
>         SqlDataReader rdr = null;
> 
>         public void askSQL (string sqlQuestion)
>         {
> 
>             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
>             cmd.CommandText = sqlQuestion;
>             cmd.Connection = connector;
>             try
>             {
>                 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
>                 while (rdr.Read())
>                 {
> 
>                 }
> 
>             }
>             catch (Exception e)
>             {
>                 MessageBox.Show("Fel vid anslutningen!" + e);
>             }
>         }
```

My error message is saying that the connection hasn't been properly initalized. Sorry for grammar misstakes and my confusion. Completely new to programming :)

Answer (score 1):

In your second button click event you are declaring another connect object. This is not the same as the one in your first button. The askSQL() method is expecting the connection to already be initialised. To do this you must run the first button code in the second button event.

```
private void askBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 sqlQuestion = sqlQuestiontF.Text;
 username = initialTf.Text;
 adress = adressTf.Text;

 connect conn = new connect();
 conn.myConnection(username, adress);

 conn.askSQL(sqlQuestion);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. Now I'm wondering on how I will retrieve the data I get from the SqlQuery and how to send it back to the view class. Do you know how and what is the best (listbox etc.) to use to send back a resultset?

Comment: Take the datareader declaration out of the askSQL method and expose it as a property of the connect class then it will be accessible from your form. On the form use a datagridview to display the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the connector.Open() in the code.

```
    class connect
{
    SqlConnection connector;
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;

    public void askSQL(string sqlQuestion)
    {
        try
        {
            using (connector = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String here"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = sqlQuestion;
                cmd.Connection = connector;

                    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    using (rdr)
                    {
                        while (rdr.Read())
                        {

                        }
                    }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (connector.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                connector.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Fel vid anslutningen!" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The conn.Open() is inside the myConnection class. I wanted to seperate the connection class and the sql command class. Do you perhaps know what the return type of a sql query is? My brain is working hard on figuring out how to get the answer back onto the screen.